# Kotlin Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I'm using Kotlin Exposed for ORM in my Web application.
I have an Entity User and it was created in the database(PostgreSQL)
I have a problem when I want to find a value in a table(User), show me this Error

> Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:
>   column users.emailSituation does not exist   Hint: Perhaps you meant
>   to reference the column "users.emailsituation".   Position: 59

My database is postgresql

User Entity:

```
object Users : IntIdTable() {
    val name = text("name").index()
    val family = text("family").index()
    val email = text("email").index()
    val emailSituation = bool("emailSituation")
    val mobile = long("mobile").index()
}

class User(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<User>(Users)

    var name by Users.name
    var family by Users.family
    var email by Users.email
    var emailSituation by Users.emailSituation
    var mobile by Users.mobile
}
```

find a value :

```
transaction {
        logger.addLogger(StdOutSqlLogger)
 println("User: ${User.find { Users.mobile eq 87654 }.joinToString {it.name}}")
    }
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: Which version of Kotlin/Exposed are you using? Did you create your tables with Exposed or are you just using Exposed to access them?

Comment: @msrd0 I'm using the last version of Kotlin/ Exposed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to indicate that it is trying to query for a column called `emailSituation`, but only `emailsitutation` is available. This might have to do with how the query is ultimately being constructed by your library. [Postgres will generally accept anything and lowercase it for column names unless you quote it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) (which is probably out of your control). To get around this, try lowercasing the name of the column you map to:

Change:

```
val emailSituation = bool("emailSituation")
```

To:

```
val emailSituation = bool("emailsituation")
                                ^
                                +-- That's the difference
```

Comment: this shouldn't be necessary in the latest version of exposed: https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/125